# How to recover data from failed HDD w/ ext4 partitions?

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover files from linux ext4 harddrive](https://superuser.com/questions/171673/how-to-recover-files-from-linux-ext4-harddrive)

My WD HDD failed (5th failed WD). Unfortunately I had some small but important files on it without backup. It's not mountable, because when I try boot from Ubuntu live CD it will try to mount automatically, then gives an error, then again mount attempt/error... What I need is somehow to recover whatever data is possible from `/etc` folder. Any idea what options I have?

Comment: How did it fail?  Hardware?  Partition table?  Corrupted sectors?  Corrupted superblock?  What have you tried to look at besides mounting?

Comment: Hardware failure, S.M.A.R.T test is failing. I've tried some windows based software called "Linux Data Recovery Software". However, it doesn't show any files in `/etc` dir.

Comment: wtf? This is completely different case. One is deleted by `rm` another is failed hardware! It's been second time my question is being closed by the same person without reading it!

Comment: The solution to both is exactly the same if it can be done with software.

Comment: There is no absolute solution to this. The routines and software for recovery of healthy hard drive and damaged one are different!

Comment: The software tools available are the same.  If you've already tried them you should have mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try DDRescue (http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) to dump a image of the drive in question and mount the image.

Comment: If your drive hardware is intact this would work.  And if it's not?

Comment: Of course this will only work if the hardware is operable (since you kinda need the hardware to access the data). If the hardware has failed you either a) replace the hardware (like the controller card) with identical hardware from an identical device or b) Send it to a data recovery specialist and pay a large sum of money.

Comment: Some data is readable. For example I have Windows NTFS partition and able to copy everything from that partition. What I need is some software, which will try to find files on demaged Ext4 partition(where not all sectors may be readable) and then recover those files on external storage.

Comment: I mean the software to scan device without mounting it...

Comment: @JustinPearce it's possible that the OP thinks the drive is completely failed, but it just doesn't respond normally in the OS. ddrescue can recover drives in those situations. For example, I had a drive which was failing (slowly). The read speed was decreasing steadily (was 200 KiB/sec at one point) and the drive would pause for 20 seconds every now and again. My file manager program didn't know what to do with that. But ddrescue recovered 80% of the drive, albeit after several weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start with anything like partition recover run:

```
fsck -t ext4 -b 32768 <device>
```

If that doesn't work try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), or [Scalpel](http://www.digitalforensicssolutions.com/Scalpel/)

This also seems to be a duplicate of [How to recover files from linux ext4 harddrive](https://superuser.com/questions/171673/how-to-recover-files-from-linux-ext4-harddrive)