# How to recover an external hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have a 2TB external hard disk. Suddenly it's not being detected. The file-system is ntfs, but the partition table might be corrupted:

```
$ sudo parted -l /dev/sdb
...
...


Model: WD Elements 10B8 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  2000GB  2000GB  ntfs
```

Here's how it looks in Windows:

[image]

Is there any way I can recover the data on disk?

Let me know if I can provide any additional info.

Comment: @tinkerbeast heres a good superuser question, http://superuser.com/questions/133799/how-do-i-restore-a-partition-without-losing-the-data

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover files from linux ext4 harddrive](http://superuser.com/questions/171673/how-to-recover-files-from-linux-ext4-harddrive)

Answer (score 1):

The steps I would take are:

1. Get a second hard drive of the same or larger dimensions (and another
   disk to pull data off if need be)
2. Get a USB stick running Linux - a TestDisk LiveCD or something else which
   you can boot and has the testdisk suite.
3. VERY CAREFULLY bitcopy the old disk (not the partition, the whole disk)
   to the new disk using ddrescue (or dd at a push).  Make sure you don't
   copy the new drive onto the old drive.
4. Remove old disk, and do operations on new disk -

   1. Attempt to fix the partition table with testdisk.
   2. If that fails attempt to pull the files you can off the raw 
      filesystem using photorec (part of the testdisk suite).  You will
      need an additional disk.

Comment: Great advice to make a clone first. That way any future efforts won't be nearly as risky. Instructions for using ddrescue to clone here - http://datarecovery.com/rd/how-to-clone-hard-disks-with-ddrescue/